# React: Client & Server way to render children to string

Tags: reactjs, next.js, render-to-string

How can I render the children as a string in React 18/Next 13?

React says `renderToString` is not suggested on the client, and it's not clear to me how to render it on the server.

The documentation [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code) gives an example but it's not clear how it works in an actual react component as I get errors that I cannot create another node if the previous one wasn't removed from the head.

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const div = document.createElement('div');
const root = createRoot(div);
flushSync(() => {
  root.render(<MyIcon />);
});
console.log(div.innerHTML); // For example, "<svg>...</svg>"
```

[Source](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code)

Whether I get the data on the server or client side, just looking for a working example either or.

```js
function ExampleChildComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-500 w-20 h-20">
      Hello I am a green box
      <button className="bg-blue-100 px-6 py-3">I am a button</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function LogChild({ children }: any) {
  // How do you get the children to a string?
  console.log(someFn(children));
  // Interested in both an output showing <GreenBox />
  // and/or the parsed version which shows the stuff inside GreenBox


  return (
    <p>Logged!</p>
  )
}

function App(){
  return (
    <LogChild>
      <ExampleChildComponent />
    </LogChild>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, if there's an open source project that I can just study works too. Google is very sparse in examples for this question. Either that or answers are pre React 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works.

Create a `div`, call the `createRoot()` function on that div. Then render the component into that root and the code will be the `innerHTML` of the div.

```js
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

function Example() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const root = createRoot(div);
    flushSync(() => root.render(<MyComponent />)); 
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
    setCode(div.innerHTML);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <code>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(code, null, 2)}</pre>
      </code>
      <div className="flex space-x-4">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Get code</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCode("")}>Clear code</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```